# Hourly average with time()

Tags: mysql, sql, time, average

is there a possibility of a single SQL query to get my hourly average data?

My table looks like this:

```
| count | time   | 
|   5   | time() |
|   4   | time() |
```

And it repeats every 24 hour.. I would like to get an average count of every hour in the day ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean... you mean MySQL?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might resemble what you want

```
select hour(time) thehour, avg(count) average
from yourtable
group by hour(time)
```

I hope those are not your real column names.  If they are, you'll have to do something because they are also sql keywords.  I don't work with mySql, so I don't know exactly what.